# Throwing Exception for UPDATE query if WHERE get empty result

Tags: java, spring-data, hql

Inside the controller layer, I get two parameters `id` of `Strategy` entity and new `status` for the update.

```
@PostMapping("/{id}/status/update")
public ResponseEntity<Long> updateStatus(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id,
                                         @NotNull @RequestBody Map<String, String> status) {
```

I need the validate `id` and if `Strategy` does not exist throw exception to the client.

Method in the repository:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Strategy s SET s.status =:status WHERE s.id = :id")
void updateStatusById(@NotNull Long id, @NotNull String status);
```

Obvious the solution is to use `findById(ID id)` of `JpaRepository` but this gives addition query to the database. As a midterm solution, I can use a single transaction for two queries like this:

In `StrategyService`:

```
@Transactional
public void update(@NotNull Long id, @NotNull String status) {
    strategyRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
    updateStatusById(id, status);
}
```

This single transaction but still a couple of queries. Very important to hold the hight speed of this query due to it call extremely often. How I can throw `Exception` directly from `updateStatusById` without addition query? Maybe somehow modifying HQL query or use native SQL or add `default` implementation?

Comment: (1) `update` is redundant with `POST`/`PUT`. (2) It's convenient for the caller to make this method return `ResponseEntity<Strategy>` with the updated value. (3) You simplify your controller by using `@PathVariable("id") Strategy strategy`; Spring Data will resolve it automatically.

Comment: what database are you using ?

Comment: @Deadpool postrges

Comment: @chrylis -on strike- yes but it's not magic it's the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
void updateStatusById(@NotNull Long id, @NotNull String status);
```

one could define the method as

```
int updateStatusById(@NotNull Long id, @NotNull String status);
```

In this case, the returned value is the number of updated entities/rows in the database. This is a [JDBC feature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and incorporated within Spring.

Now, after the query has been executed (`int updated = updateStatusById(id, status);`), one can check how many entities were updated. If `0` elements were updated, an `Exception` can be thrown.